# Stuck at the Thinkpad startup screen on first reboot after Wubi

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, thinkpad, wubi

I have just downloaded Wubi and Ubuntu and rebooted around 10 minutes ago. Oddly enough, I am stuck at the ThinkPad screen:

[image]

What should I do from here? I have tried clicking the ThinkVantage button, but the computer is un-reactive. At the very least, can someone help me to start up windows again?

Thanks!

Comment: If you reboot, does it continue to hang here? or does it move on to wubi?

Answer (score 2):

Check the USB port for any USB drives that are still plugged in. Most of the time, it could be problem with a boot device still being tried, other than your hard drive.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. My mp3 player was connected to the laptop, so laptop was trying to boot from it or just to enumerate it, whatever. After disconnecting mp3 player my laptop started to reboot just fine :)